# Boolean values are not mapping properly when using multiset in JOOQ

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jooq

The ProductCategoryDto class :

```
public class ProductCategoryDto {
    private UUID id;

    private String title;

    private String description;

    private Timestamp updatedAt;

    private Timestamp createdAt;

    private List<CategoryAttribute> attributes;
}
```

CategoryAttribute class :

```
public class CategoryAttribute {
    private UUID id;

    private String title;

    private String attributeType;

    private Boolean multiValued;

    private Boolean nullable;

    private Boolean isUnique;

    private Integer indexValue;

    private String description;

    private Boolean isActive;

    private UUID categoryId;

    private Timestamp updatedAt;

    private Timestamp createdAt;
}
```

The query with needs to be executed is

```
this.dslContext.select(
                PRODUCT_CATEGORY.asterisk(),
                multiset(
                    selectFrom(CATEGORY_ATTRIBUTE).where(CATEGORY_ATTRIBUTE.CATEGORY_ID.eq(PRODUCT_CATEGORY.ID))
                ).as("attributes")
            )
            .from(PRODUCT_CATEGORY)
            .where(PRODUCT_CATEGORY.ID.eq(id))
            .fetchOneInto(ProductCategoryDto.class);
```

The output for the query is

```
{
    "id": "7e8d5560-62dc-48fc-b835-65642024fa0a",
    "title": "Mobile",
    "description": "It is an electronic device",
    "updatedAt": "2022-02-12T08:29:04.923+00:00",
    "createdAt": "2022-02-12T08:28:14.764+00:00",
    "attributes": [
        {
            "id": "8bfd98ca-101f-43ef-8a53-770e933265b6",
            "title": "RAM",
            "attributeType": "8",
            "multiValued": null,
            "nullable": null,
            "isUnique": null,
            "indexValue": 1,
            "description": "description",
            "isActive": null,
            "categoryId": "7e8d5560-62dc-48fc-b835-65642024fa0a",
            "updatedAt": "2022-02-12T08:42:02.297+00:00",
            "createdAt": "2022-02-12T08:42:02.297+00:00"
        }
    ]
}
```

Database create statements:

```
Product Category:
CREATE TABLE `product_category` (
  `id` varchar(36) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `title` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)

Attribute table:
CREATE TABLE `category_attribute` (
  `id` varchar(36) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `attribute_type` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `category_id` varchar(36) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `index_value` int NOT NULL,
  `is_active` bit(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT b'1',
  `is_unique` bit(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT b'0',
  `multi_valued` bit(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT b'0',
  `nullable` bit(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT b'0',
  `title` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

Code generation configuration in pom.xml:

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
                <artifactId>jooq-codegen-maven</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>jooq-codegen</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <jdbc>
                                <driver>com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</driver>
                                <!--suppress UnresolvedMavenProperty -->
                                <url>${spring.datasource.url}</url>
                                <!--suppress UnresolvedMavenProperty -->
                                <user>${spring.datasource.username}</user>
                                <!--suppress UnresolvedMavenProperty -->
                                <password>${spring.datasource.password}</password>
                            </jdbc>
                            <generator>
                                <database>
                                    <name>org.jooq.meta.mysql.MySQLDatabase</name>
                                    <includes>.*</includes>
                                    <excludes/>
                                    <!--suppress UnresolvedMavenProperty -->
                                    <inputSchema>${database.name}</inputSchema>

                                    <forcedTypes>
                                        <forcedType>
                                            <userType>java.util.UUID</userType>
                                            <converter>com.project.ecommerce.converters.jooq.JooqUUIDConverter</converter>
                                            <includeExpression>.*.ID</includeExpression>
                                            <includeTypes>.*</includeTypes>
                                        </forcedType>
                                    </forcedTypes>
                                </database>
                                <generate>
                                    <pojos>false</pojos>
                                    <pojosEqualsAndHashCode>
                                        true
                                    </pojosEqualsAndHashCode>
                                    <javaTimeTypes>true</javaTimeTypes>
                                    <fluentSetters>true</fluentSetters>
                                </generate>
                                <target>
                                    <packageName>
                                        com.jooq.models
                                    </packageName>
                                    <directory>
                                        target/generated-sources/jooq
                                    </directory>
                                </target>
                            </generator>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

I am getting all the boolean fields as null while they are not null in Actual data.
How to map the boolean fields properly so that there will be no null values in boolean fields when using multiset

Comment: What jOOQ version, what database product, and what `MULTISET` emulation setting (`Settings.emulateMultiset`) are you using?

Comment: JOOQ version: 3.16.3, database: MySQL, 
Multiset emulation setting (how to know about it)?

Comment: Thanks, will investigate. The setting is in `Configuration.settings()`. But if you didn't tamper with it, you're probably using the default.

Comment: I'm afraid I cannot reproduce this on my side. The `BOOLEAN` projections seem to be working correctly. How did you implement your boolean columns in your generated code? Using a `Converter` or `Binding`? Can you please add: 1) the table definitions (`CREATE TABLE`), 2) the relevant bits of your code generation configuration?

Comment: I have added both the database create statements and the code generation config in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a bug, which should be fixed, soon, in jOOQ 3.17.0, 3.16.5, 3.15.9: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/13089

It is related to jOOQ not serialising `BIT(1)` values correctly when using the SQL/JSON `MULTISET` emulation. Things would look better if you had used `TINYINT` instead of `BIT(1)` to encode your boolean values. Note also that future versions of jOOQ might fix their understanding of the `BIT` type, which is more of a `java.lang.BitSet` than a `java.lang.Boolean`: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/10323

While you cannot currently influence the SQL/JSON emulation, you could cast your `BIT` columns to `BOOLEAN` explicitly, as such: `CATEGORY_ATTRIBUTE.NULLABLE.cast(SQLDataType.BOOLEAN)`

Comment: Ok, but I have another doubt why does the database float value is always generated by JOOQ generator as Double instead of Float?

Comment: @SaiUttej: Please ask a new question. It's not related to this one, and the Stack Overflow comment section is poorly suited for such explanations