# Unknown column sql error while using jooq

Tags: java, sql, jooq

Query:

```java
this.dslContext.select(
            ROLE.asterisk(),
            multiset(
                select(PERMISSION.asterisk())
                    .from(ROLE_PERMISSION)
                    .innerJoin(PERMISSION)
                    .on(ROLE_PERMISSION.PERMISSION_ID.eq(PERMISSION.ID))
                    .where(ROLE_PERMISSION.ROLE_ID.eq(ROLE.ID))
            ).as("permissions")
        ).from(ROLE)
            .where(ROLE.ID.eq(id))
            .fetchOneInto(Role.class)
```

Error:

```
jOOQ; bad SQL grammar [set @t = @@group_concat_max_len; set @@group_concat_max_len = 4294967295; select `users`.`role`.*, (select coalesce(json_merge_preserve('[]', concat('[', group_concat(json_array(`v0`, `v1`) separator ','), ']')), json_array()) from (select `users`.`permission`.`id` as `v0`, `users`.`permission`.`name` as `v1` from `users`.`role_permission` join `users`.`permission` on `users`.`role_permission`.`permission_id` = `users`.`permission`.`id` where `users`.`role_permission`.`role_id` = `users`.`role`.`id`) as `t`) as `permissions` from `users`.`role` where `users`.`role`.`id` = ?; set @@group_concat_max_len = @t;]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'users.role.id' in 'where clause'.
```

Database: MYSQL, Database Name: 'users', JOOQ Version: 3.16.6

Comment: What MySQL version are you using?

Comment: MySQL version : 8.0.28

Comment: That's weird, MySQL 8 should be capable of running this query. It's a known issue in MySQL 5.7: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/12045. Would changing `ROLE_PERMISSION.ROLE_ID.eq(ROLE.ID)` to `ROLE_PERMISSION.ROLE_ID.eq(id)` work around it?

Comment: Yes, it is working with ROLE_PERMISSION.ROLE_ID.eq(id) but not with ROLE_PERMISSION.ROLE_ID.eq(ROLE.ID)

Comment: Here, since I am getting only 1 record so it's ok if I keep the id directly. But I can not do the same thing for the get-all query

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue on MySQL 8.0.28 in a variety of integration tests. There seems to be a bug somewhere, or a misconfiguration. If you could provide a fully self contained example in a bug report, I could investigate it: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/new/choose

Comment: According to the docs, correlated derived tables are supported starting from MySQL 8.0.14: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html. I don't see what else could be wrong with the jOOQ generated query. A workaround is to express an equivalent query using [`MULTISET_AGG()`](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/column-expressions/aggregate-functions/multiset-agg-function/), which is less powerful but doesn't have this restriction on older MySQL versions.

Comment: Still trying to assess what could possibly have gone wrong here. Does the query also fail when you run it directly in MySQL Workbench, or similar? How is it different from your previous queries, e.g. this one: https://stackoverflow.com/q/71090662/521799 ? Can you narrow it down to a specific API usage?

Comment: I was just checking the server in which I am running my database its version is actually 5.7.38 and my local MySQL version is 8.0.28
It is working fine in the local MySQL database
Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correlating derived tables isn't supported in MySQL 5.7. Support has been added only in MySQL 8.0.14:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html

jOOQ currently can't work around this limitation, see:
https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/12045

The solution is either:

- Upgrade your MySQL version
- Use a [`MULTISET_AGG`](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/column-expressions/aggregate-functions/multiset-agg-function/) based approach instead